# Reusable function inside jQuery hover function

Tags: jquery

Below is my jQuery code:   (You can see the whole source code and test it [here](http://codepen.io/vinhnghi223/pen/jsavn))

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#pclass").hover(function() {
        $("p[class]").css("border", "3px solid red");
      }, function() {
        $("p[class]").css("border", "none");
      }
    );
    $("#pidpara1").hover(function() {
        $("p[id=para1]").css("border", "3px solid red");
      }, function() {
        $("p[id=para1]").css("border", "none");
      }
    );
  ...
  }
```

You see, I used the `css("border", "3px solid red");` and `css("border", "none");` again many times.
So how can I make the code reusable properly in this case? (You can see the whole source code and test it [here](http://codepen.io/vinhnghi223/pen/jsavn))[1](http://codepen.io/vinhnghi223/pen/jsavn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figure out what parts of the operation are the same and what parts are different, then create a function that accepts arguments for the parts that vary:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    addBorderOnHover("#pclass", "p[class]");
    addBorderOnHover("#pidpara1", "p[id=para1]"); // "p[id=para1]" can be "#para1", of course

    function addBorderOnHover(hoverSel, borderSel) {
        $(hoverSel).hover(function() {
            $(borderSel).css("border", "3px solid red");
          }, function() {
            $(borderSel).css("border", "none");
          }
        );
    }
});
```

Side note: Also note that I removed the quotes around `document`, which shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thank you but I fail to apply your code. However base on your answer, I made a  hoverIn(select) and hoverOut(select) function and it works.

Comment: For example you can check this, a simpler case: http://jsbin.com/exEzoRo/2/edit . It just dint work.

Comment: @AmazingQuestion: And if you look in the web console of your browser, you'll see an error telling you why: It has an errant `;`. Corrected version: http://jsbin.com/EpeWabeN/1/edit (The code above had an error as well, although a different one [a missing `}`], which I've added.)